# Running npm install from Docker container - ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime; etc

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to run `npm install` from a container instead of having to worry about Node versions on my host machine.

Here is how I'm setting up the container and running `npm install`, but notice I'm getting a ton of warnings and then just errors:

```
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis> docker run -d -i --name node -v ${pwd}:/app -w /app node:10.20.1
bc30edfadd852e7fc104c9b96baf00b48c19539fc681b391c1477a90b6f3eafb

PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis> docker exec node npm install
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/jsdom-97619baf/LICENSE.txt'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/jsdom-97619baf/README.md'
npm WARN nmis@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN nmis@1.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await/-/plugin-syntax-top-level-await-7.8.3.tgz
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/bootstrap-0408c22e/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/node-sass-231f7636/src/libsass/src/ast.hpp'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-react-e0dc56f2/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-import-f1c3e673/lib/rules/no-restricted-paths.js'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-import-f1c3e673/lib/rules/no-self-import.js'npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-import-f1c3e673/lib/rules/no-unassigned-import.js'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/acorn-fb4e7218/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/jquery-f43315cf/dist/jquery.slim.js'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/socket.io-client-99ebea71/dist/socket.io.slim.dev.js'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eslint-8193e18d/LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/font-awesome-3b8746c7/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tarball tarball data for jquery@3.5.1 (sha512-XwIBPqcMn57FxfT+Go5pzySnm4KWkT1Tv7gjrpT1srtf8Weynl6R273VJ5GjkRb51IzMp5nbaPjJXMWeju2MKg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for eslint@2.13.1 (sha1-5MyPoPAJ+4KaquI4VaKTYL4fbBE=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/@babel/parser-bc1c7734/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime
npm WARN tarball tarball data for bootstrap@4.5.0 (sha512-Z93QoXvodoVslA+PWNdk23Hze4RBYIkpb5h8I2HY2Tu2h7A0LpAgLcyrhrSUyo2/Oxm2l1fRZPs1e5hnxnliXA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for browser-sync-ui@2.26.12 (sha512-PkAJNf/TfCFTCkQUfXplR2Kp/+/lbCWFO9lrgLZsmxIhvMLx2pYZFBbTBIaem8qjXhld9ZcESUC8EdU5VWFJgQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-11T10_10_04_667Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis>
```

The versions seem to be the same between host and controller:

```
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis> docker exec -it node bash
root@bc30edfadd85:/app# node -v
v10.20.1
root@bc30edfadd85:/app# npm -v
6.14.4
root@bc30edfadd85:/app# exit
exit
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis> node -v
v10.20.1
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis> npm -v
6.14.4
PS C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis>
```

I tried search on google couldn't find specifically `ENOSYS: function not implemented, futime`. Any help? Perhaps I'm not setting up my container properly?

Comment: If you're on a Windows host, but with a Linux container, the `-v` option is injecting a wrong-architecture `node_modules` tree into your container.  Delete that option to use the code that's actually built into the image.

Comment: Hi. Yeh that seems to be the case. If I run the same commands in my Ubuntu, it works as intended. So it's not specifically the node_modules/ directory that I need belonging to the host, however the source files (e.g. src/scss) files will sit on the host, and the destination files (e.g. dist/css) files also need to be written to the host. Is this possible with Windows files?

Comment: One of the design goals of Docker is to isolate the files in the image from any content on the host.  I'd recommend installing Node on the host and using that for day-to-day development; if you need Docker for deployment purposes, `docker build` your code into an image, and run it without a `-v` option.